# how to display a mysql table column in different div tags with php and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, html

The following php page is getting the values from mysql table :
its  getTechnoXchange.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$host="localhost";// Host name
$db_name="parth"; // Database name

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("parth") or die('Could not connect to database' . mysql_error());




$pricequery="SELECT price FROM technoxchange;" ;
$result=mysql_query($pricequery);

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo $row['price'];
echo "<br/>";

}
?>
```

But I want that my jQuery to get that array and display in different div tags.

My javascript in a different php file "TechnoXchange.php"  :

```
var p;
$.get("getTechnoXchange.php", function(data){
        p= Array.prototype.slice.call(data);

});

document.getElementById('priceUnicus').innerHTML = p[0];
document.getElementById('priceHire').innerHTML = p[1];
document.getElementById('priceMonsterArena').innerHTML = p[2];
```

Its not getting displayed in the different div tags. Waiting for your answers!!

Comment: is the same code up top what is in getTechnoExchange.php? Because according to that string you are only selecting the price column and then trying to split that into 3 columns. At least thats what it looks like on this end, hard to tell with the code you provided.

Comment: I don't see the relation between your PHP and your javascript

Answer (score 2):

From the limited information provided above, i would suggest json_encoding the result and sending it to the client so the prices are easier to work with. This is some rough code.

For the php

```
$pricequery="SELECT price FROM technoxchange;"
$result=mysql_query($pricequery);

while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $prices [] = $row['price'];
}

echo json_encode( array( 'prices' => $prices ) );
```

For the js

```
var p;
$.get("getTechnoXchange.php", function(data){
    p = data.prices;
});

$('#priceUnicus').html( p[0] ); 
$('#priceHire').html( p[1] ); 
$('#priceMonsterArena').html( p[2] );
```

Comment: How can I use getJSON() methode instead of just get() ?